# I want to load data in Edittext of fragments with value saved in sharedpreference but data isn't been loaded

Tags: php, android, android-fragments, sharedpreferences, android-volley

```
package in.co.mdabba.m_dabbawala;

 import android.content.Context;
 import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;



 public class Fragment_MyProfile extends Fragment {


public EditText Firstname,Lastname,Phoneno;



@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
 View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_myprofile, container, false);
   run();
    return view;
}

public void run(){
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getActivity().getSharedPreferences("logininfo", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    String emailid = sharedPreferences.getString("emailid","");
    Firstname =(EditText) getView().findViewById(R.id.firstname);
    Lastname = (EditText) getView().findViewById(R.id.lastname);
    Phoneno = (EditText)getView().findViewById(R.id.phoneno);
    String b1url =  "https://e705bb27.ngrok.io/1/b1.php?emailid="+emailid;
    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, b1url,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    try{
                        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
                        JSONArray result = jsonObject.getJSONArray("result");
                        JSONObject Data = result.getJSONObject(0);
                        String f_name = Data.getString("First_name");
                        String l_name =Data.getString("Last_name");
                        String phone_no = Data.getString("Phone_no");
                        Firstname.setText(f_name);
                        Lastname.setText(l_name);
                        Phoneno.setText(phone_no);
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }
            },new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"Something went wrong try again later!!!",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            error.printStackTrace();
        }
    });
    mysingleton.getInstance(getActivity()).addtoRequest(stringRequest);
}
}
```

I want to load the user details form mysql after login to do that i have used sharedpreferences to store email address which will be used to complete the php query and load data in Edittext but after login my app crashes and i m using volley library for retriving the data.[logcat](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rsz98.png)

Fragment_myproflie.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/lightgrey"
android:focusable="true"
android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
android:orientation="vertical">


<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:text="Edit Profile"
    android:textSize="22sp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />
 <LinearLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_margin="10dp"
android:background="@color/white"
android:orientation="vertical">
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:text="First Name:"
    android:textSize="12sp" />
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/firstname"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="8dp"
    android:text="dd"
    android:textColor="#000000"/>
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:text="Last Name:"
    android:textSize="12sp" />
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/lastname"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:text="I"
    android:textColor="#000000"/>
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:text="Phone no:"
    android:textSize="12sp" />
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/phoneno"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:text="lv"
    android:textColor="#000000"/>
<Button
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="13dp"
    android:background="#000080"
    android:text="@string/UpdateDetails"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:textStyle="bold" />
</LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Comment: show me your Logcat error .

Comment: jst check the description @SantoshBachkar i have uploaded it

Comment: post xml of fragment_myprofile

Comment: Done @JanardhanR

Comment: thanks can you please tell which line no 40 in Fragmentprofile.java

Comment: public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_myprofile, container, false);
       run();
        return view;
    }              at the closing brace is line no 40 the oncreateView method

Comment: ok thanks please check posted answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you may be getting this  record ,so before using **setText make sure values are not null** and values which you are retriving doesnt match i.e

```
 {"result":[{"Firstname":null,"Lastname":null,"Phoneno":null}]}     

 String f_name = Data.getString("First_name");//it should be Firstname
 String l_name =Data.getString("Last_name");//it should be Lastname
 String phone_no = Data.getString("Phone_no");//it should be Phoneno

   if(f_name!=null){
     Firstname.setText(f_name);
    }
   if(l_name!=null){
    Lastname.setText(l_name);
    } if (phone_no!=null){
     Phoneno.setText(phone_no);
   }
```

Comment: Intent is working fine but Fields aren't loaded they are just default

Comment: sorry i couldnt get you they are deafult means ?you havent used any intent in this class.can you tell what are you getting in f_name,l_name

Comment: just predefined value in Edittext of the xml file @Janardhan R

Comment: but what are you getting in  f_name,l_name,

Comment: Firstname.setText("test);//try this for test weather it is working or not we will know

Comment: checked just passed the wrong name in    String f_name = Data.getString("First_name"); replaced First_name with Firstname thats it data loaded into fields

Answer (score 1):

At the moment you call getView() you havent set the View yet, pass the view as an argument to your run method and use that view instead of getView()

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
 View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_myprofile, container, false);
   run(view);
    return view;
}
public void run(View view){
 SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getActivity().getSharedPreferences("logininfo", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
 String emailid = sharedPreferences.getString("emailid","");
 Firstname =(EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.firstname);
}
```

Comment: I have done as suggested by @Junaid Hafeez but data isn't be loaded in the Edittext

Answer (score 0):

Probably, `getView()` is null, which you are using in `run()` method.

```
Firstname =(EditText) getView().findViewById(R.id.firstname);
Lastname = (EditText) getView().findViewById(R.id.lastname);
Phoneno = (EditText)getView().findViewById(R.id.phoneno);
```

make a global field, `View view` and in your `onCreateView()` method, assign your view to this global `view` and use it later for binding your views like

```
Firstname =(EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.firstname);
```

Comment: My activity started but i am unable to retrive values in Edit text @Junaid Hafeez

Comment: to retrieve values you need too use Firstname.getText().tostring();